# Maven can't resolve the dependency it just found

Tags: maven

Maven must be losing its mind.

I added a dependency using Netbeans Add Dependency dialog.  I searched for `jax-rs-ri`.  It updated the index from central and showed several versions of `jax-rs-ri`.  I selected `1.9.1` and it added this to the `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.ri</groupId>
        <artifactId>jax-rs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Looks right, but when I build I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project reply-to.test-web: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project jms:reply-to.test-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not find artifact com.sun.jersey.ri:jax-rs-ri:jar:1.10-b03 in 
central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

I've also tried changing the repository the following with the same results:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This was working earlier today.  Did something just get broken with Maven?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In these cases it's worth to check the local repository (usually `c:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\ri\jax-rs-ri` or `/home/<username>/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jax-rs-ri`) and Central: 
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.sun.jersey.ri|jax-rs-ri|1.9.1|pom
(The important part now is the "Available Downloads" table.)

So, there isn't any `jar` file just a `zip` (and the POM). You should use `<type>zip</type>` in your dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.ri</groupId>
    <artifactId>jax-rs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

Since it's a zip maybe you want to unpack it. This answer could help: [Unzip dependency in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388661/unzip-dependency-in-maven)

Please note that `1.9.1` is not the latest `jax-rs-ri` version and your Maven uses `1.10-b03`. If you want to force it to use `1.9.1` you have to use `<version>[1.9.1]</version>` inside the `dependency` tag.

Comment: Adding <type>zip</type> fixed it.  Without it I still get Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/ri/jax-rs-ri/1.9.1/jax-rs-ri-1.9.1.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/ri/jax-rs-ri/1.9.1/jax-rs-ri-1.9.1.jar  so it looks like mvn finds the .jar files.  Strange.

Comment: It downloads the zip, believe me :) The zip contains the jars but you have to unpack it if you'd like to use them.