# Get a reference to the folder where maven wan initially executed

Tags: maven

I have a multi module project:

```
grandparent module
     > parent module
        > child module
     > parent module
```

When I run the maven command I will execute like this

```
c:\projects\myproject\grandparent module\mvn package
```

I have defined my PDM configuration in the grandparent module.

```
                <rulesets>
                   <ruleset>${basedir}/pmd-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
```

The trouble is that every project needs to have `pmd-ruleset.xml`.  I want to put it in the `grandparent module` and for all project to use it from here.

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Have just had a brief search in SO, seems similar questions has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885048/share-specific-pmd-rulesets-across-multi-module-maven-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to share a PMD, checkstyle, findbugs, and etc configuration across a multi-module Maven project is similar.  You may visit Checkstyle Maven plugin for the detail.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html

In short, in Maven, resources are not inherited from parent project.  You can create a separate module to contain all these shared QA configurations, and use this QA module as the dependency in other child modules to execute the PMD/Checkstyle/Findbugs plugins.