# maven How to use requireUnpack

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin

Hi I have the following from a pom.xml of a spring boot app:

```
<dependencies>

--omitted dependencies--

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pps.model</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/pps.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <requiresUnpack>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>pps.model</groupId>
                        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </requiresUnpack>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

the pps.model dependecy needs to be extracted before running the app, I don't know how to do this, Can anybody shine me a light?

Comment: This would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388661/unzip-dependency-in-maven