# How to Unzip arbitrary files using pom.xml in maven

Tags: maven, unzip

I have a zip file in the path "C:\ptc\Windchill_10.1\Windchill" . Please can anyone tell me how to unzip this file using maven

Answer (score 17):

Maven has a plugin to work with Ant. With that plugin you can create Ant-Tasks, this tasks are a sequence of xml instructions that you can use to (virtually) anything you need.

A piece of code that you can use as inspiration:

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
               <tasks>
                  <echo message="unzipping file" />
                  <unzip src="output/inner.zip" dest="output/" />
               </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
               <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

source: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html

Comment: A more modern, similar solution is with _TrueZip_ as stated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30484505/7251133), which I could sucessfully use.

Answer (score 0):

Maven has a plugin named dependency plugin which helps you deal with artifacts, you can check documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html)

If your requirement is to unpack the dependencies and their transitive dependencies, take a look [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-project-dependencies.html)

You can also take a look at solution provided in question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264064/unpack-zip-in-zip-with-maven)

Comment: It is clear that galme is not referring to a dependency, and so this is not a solution. There are many questions already devoted to unzipping dependencies, but few if any to unzipping files on a given path.

Comment: @Mitch the reason I mentioned unzipping dependency is because the folder mentioned by op is where the windchill product keeps jar files typically. I realized that op is trying to open those jar files hence my answer in that direction.