# Unzip and re zip a file using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, build, zip, pom.xml

**Question**: is there any way in Maven (without resorting to an ant plugin) to unzip a file, cd into the directory, remove the file, and the rezip it, all as part of the build?

This is necessary as it is a complex build and also do not want to have to use gradle to accomplish this task.

Comment: Can you explain more why you need to do this? Is this ZIP generated? If so, by who and when? What file do you want to remove in it and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpack inner zips in zip with Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264064/unpack-inner-zips-in-zip-with-maven)

Comment: mvn dependency:unpack + maven-assembly-plugin for rezip

Comment: You can take a look at maven-assembly-plugin. This can handle both unzip and repackaging ...

Answer (score 2):

The requirement of unzipping, removing file and zipping again can also be met in **one single step** by the `truezip-maven-plugin` and its [`remove`](http://www.mojohaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/remove-mojo.html) goal which:

> Remove a set of files from an existing archive.

The [official](http://www.mojohaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/usage.html) examples also cover this scenario.

Given the following snippet:

```
<properties>
    <archive>${project.basedir}/sample.zip</archive>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>remove-a-file</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>remove</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <fileset>
                            <!-- note how the archive is treated as a normal file directory -->
                            <directory>${archive}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>hello.txt</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And executing:

```
mvn clean package
```

The build will process the `${archive}` file (in this case a `sample.zip` at the same level of the `pom.xml` file, that is, in the `project.basedir` directory) and remove from it the `hello.txt` file. Then rezip everything.

I just tested it successfully, you can even skip the `properties` section if not required. However, you should also carefully know that:

- The zip file should not be under version control, otherwise it would create conflicts at each build
- The behavior most probably should not be part of the default Maven build, hence good candidate for a [Maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)
- the plugin replaces the original file, so if that was an issue you could firstly copy it to another location and then process it as above. To copy it, you could use the `maven-resources-plugin` and its `copy-resources` goal.

Comment: @user1974753 did you try this solution?